# How to set max zoom in zoom_widget?

Tags: flutter, dart, widget, zooming

how to set or modify zoom_widget and add max zoom?
I use the zoom widget but it is limited by max zoom, so how do I modify zoom_widget and set the maximum zoom

Version:  zoom_widget 0.1.3

Answer (score 0):

[image]

I found a solution, just modify the code below and set it from 1 to 5